# Clone an object including not primitive types

Tags: c#, blazor

I'm creating a component for Blazor and facing an issue when I have to create at runtime an object and I want to copy most of the properties, basically to clone an object but without same properties.

For example, the class *Checkbox* has a property called *Choices*.

```
public class Checkbox : ElementBase, IElement {
    public virtual List<object>? Choices { get; set; }    
}
```

This property stores string or *CheckboxChoice*.

```
public class CheckboxChoice
{
    public string? Label { get; set; }
    public string? VisibleIf { get; set; }
}
```

So, at runtime I have to create a new instance of an object (for example Checkbox) to display the component I want. To create an instance, I use this code (*el* is an implementation of *IElement*)

```
var newInstance = el.GetType();
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(newInstance) as IElement;
```

Now, I have to copy some of the property's values from *el* to the *instance*. In order to copy all the properties I want, I use this extension

```
public static class ElementExtensions
{
    public static T CopyTo<T, S>(this T target, S source, string[] propertyNames)
    {
        if (source == null)
            return target;

        Type sourceType = typeof(S);
        Type targetType = typeof(T);
        BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | 
                             BindingFlags.Instance;

        PropertyInfo[] properties = sourceType.GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo sPI in properties)
        {
            if (!propertyNames.Contains(sPI.Name))
            {
                PropertyInfo tPI = targetType.GetProperty(sPI.Name, flags);
                if (tPI != null && tPI.CanWrite && 
                    tPI.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(sPI.PropertyType))
                {
                    tPI.SetValue(target, sPI.GetValue(source, null), null);
                }
            }
        }
        return target;
    }
}
```

The problem with this extension is that it is not copying the property *Choices* or other property that are not a primitive type.

I don't want to use *AutoMapper* because I like to have a light component without dependencies, apart from .NET6. How can I change the function to copy also the complex properties?

### Update

This is the code I use. *ElementData* has the list of components (like Checkbox and Textbox) to display.

```
public List<IElement>? RepeaterElements { get; set; }

foreach (var el in ElementData)
{
    var newInstance = el.GetType();
    var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(newElement, null);

    instance.CopyTo(data, new[] { "Parent", "Index", "QuestionNumber", "Name" });

    instance.Parent = parentName;
    instance.Index = row;
    instance.QuestionNumber = question;
    instance.Name = instance.GetElementName();

    RepeaterElements.Add(new RepeaterElement() { Element = instance, Row = row });
}
```

Comment: Do you have any debug information to share? Without knowing `S`, `T` and `propertyNames` I can't tell why the property is not copied. Although you used `IgnoreCase` flag, `Contains` is still case sensitive. And do you mean a deep copy or only a reference copy?

Comment: Deep copy because I need a new instance of the class: the reason is that if I copy for example the `name` property, the component doesn't generate a new name for the component and then I can't save the value.

Comment: One solution is to use PropertyInfo.PropertyType to check if it is not a primitive. If it isnt, generate a new instance of the type of the property and assign it to the property of the type that you are trying to clone (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.propertytype?view=net-6.0#system-reflection-propertyinfo-propertytype).

Comment: 1) If you need a deep copy, this is too broad, you have to care about any types. To clone a list, or to clone a dictionary etc... 2) Is `name` a string? So "generate a new name" doesn't mean copy, does it? 3) If the type of `instance` is `IElement`, then `sourceType` in the method is an interface type that won't return expected properties for you.

Answer (score 1):

I've always defaulted to using serialization to handle deep object copies.

Here is an example:

```
using static Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert;

var instanceOfMyClass = new MyClass()
{
    Id = 1,
    Name = "John Doe",
    Age = 21
};

Console.WriteLine(SerializeObject(instanceOfMyClass));

var copyOfMyClass = DeserializeObject<MyClass>(SerializeObject(new { instanceOfMyClass.Name, instanceOfMyClass.Age }));

Console.WriteLine(SerializeObject(copyOfMyClass));

public class MyClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

It's a simple and performant pattern on small classes.

**EDIT:**

Can also be done between classes if the Property names are the same:

```
sing static Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert;

var instanceOfMyClass = new MyClass()
{
    Id = 1,
    Name = "John Doe",
    Age = 21
};

Console.WriteLine(SerializeObject(instanceOfMyClass));

var copyOfMyClass = DeserializeObject<MySecondClass>(SerializeObject(new { instanceOfMyClass.Name, instanceOfMyClass.Age }));

Console.WriteLine(SerializeObject(copyOfMyClass));

public class MyClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class MySecondClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```